# Using OpenLayers without npm packet manager

Tags: npm, openlayers

years ago it was possible to use OL without npm packet manager.
Is this still possible?
Can anybody say why npm seems to be the "standard way" now?

Best regards, Kai

Comment: https://openlayers.org/download/